# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ProjectConfiguration

Tags: php

I am trying to clear the cache using command 'php symfony cc' but getting " Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ProjectConfiguration in /home/dev/project/devz/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 46 ". Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post the output of the following shell command: `grep -r 'class ProjectConfiguration' /home/dev/project/devz`

Comment: cant you find the cache directory and delete the contents manually?

Comment: thanks for reply ... i tried to execute grep -r command but its getting hang ... am not able to see the output ... i restarted the apache but still getting the fatal error ...

Comment: yes i tried deleting cache directory's content ... still the error is there ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens due to some bugs in PHP's FastCGI.

Try to restart it. At Ubuntu it's:

```
service php-fastcgi restart
```